# WS-SecurityPolicy + MTOM + CXF: The signature or decryption was invalid

Tags: cxf, ws-security, mtom

Currently I have implemented a web service using CXF (3.0.6) which allows the upload of validated XML data through WS-SecurityPolicy; the authentication is performed through a UsernameToken and the data is secured through symmetric encryption.
I have a problem regarding attachments, when I enable the upload of a image in base64 encoding the server got the error "The signature or decryption was invalid", but when I disable the base64 everything goes well with the rest of the data.
This is my cxf-servlet.xml:

```
    <jaxws:endpoint id="CaricamentoAPE"
                    address="/CaricamentoAPE"
                    implementor="it.enea.siape.ws.soap.CaricamentoAPE_Impl">
    <jaxws:features>
        <wsa:addressing/>
    </jaxws:features>
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="true" />
        <entry key="ws-security.store.bytes.in.attachment" value="true" />
        <entry key="exceptionMessageCauseEnabled" value="false" />
        <!-- Test X.509 + UsernameTokenValidator -->
        <entry key="ws-security.ut.validator" value-ref="LDAPUsernameTokenValidator" />
        <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value-ref="ServiceKeystorePasswordCallback"/>
        <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value="serviceKeystore.properties"/>
        <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value="serviceKeystore.properties"/> 
        <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="useReqSigCert"/>
    </jaxws:properties>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

The security policy used by me is this (there are also input and output binding, I can copy them here if needed):

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE xml>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SiapeBindingPolicy"         xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702"
xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
<sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
    <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:UsernameToken
            sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:WssUsernameToken10 />
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:UsernameToken>
    </wsp:Policy>
</sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
<sp:SymmetricBinding>
    <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Basic128 />
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
        <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
        <sp:Layout>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Strict />
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Layout>
        <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody />
        <sp:ProtectionToken>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:X509Token
                    sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference />
                        <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:X509Token>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:ProtectionToken>
    </wsp:Policy>
</sp:SymmetricBinding>
<sp:Wss11>
    <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey />
        <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
        <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint />
    </wsp:Policy>
</sp:Wss11>
<ns1:OptimizedMimeSerialization
    xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization" />
<wsam:Addressing />
```

Through the DEBUG I noticed this:

```
    25-05-2016 18:28:32 DEBUG dom.DOMReference: 391 - Expected digest: 1FXanAzDZgOhiAgrIp7+8BrGqG4=
    25-05-2016 18:28:32 DEBUG dom.DOMReference: 392 - Actual digest: GZCpbCx1dywGJIjTYooD2vn5Wi4=
    25-05-2016 18:28:32 DEBUG dom.DOMXMLSignature: 268 - Reference[#_74e28a15-9fbc-412b-b9db-669f52cf767f] is valid: false
    25-05-2016 18:28:32 DEBUG dom.DOMXMLSignature: 274 - Couldn't validate the References
    25-05-2016 18:28:32 DEBUG processor.SignatureProcessor: 428 - XML Signature verification has failed
    25-05-2016 18:28:32 DEBUG processor.SignatureProcessor: 431 - Signature Validation check: true
    25-05-2016 18:28:32 DEBUG processor.SignatureProcessor: 441 - Reference #TS-6c94d844-7455-4c4a-8397-3b064269c735 check: true
    25-05-2016 18:28:32 DEBUG processor.SignatureProcessor: 441 - Reference #UsernameToken-b87ccaae-3888-44cf-a951-4f5f066e9556 check: true
    25-05-2016 18:28:32 DEBUG processor.SignatureProcessor: 441 - Reference #_74e28a15-9fbc-412b-b9db-669f52cf767f check: false
```

By using "ws-security.store.bytes.in.attachment" now iIsee through the debug that the SOAP is correctly decrypted but it is split onto two rows "DEBUG internal.DigesterOutputStream: 88 - Pre-digested input:", I think it's a limit by logging.

I read about a second approach which implies "storeBytesInAttachment" property of WSS4J but I don't saw any example about it.

Can anyone help me?